# Can any one tell me how to increase file upload size for media in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have trouble with wordpress file uploading limit. right now i have 8MB limit. but i want to increase it to 100 MB to 200MB. Please guide me how to do it.

Comment: What have you done to make it 8MB?

Comment: its by default uploading limit of wordpress

Answer (score 2):

Take a look here : http://mynotes.farkess.com/2012/08/02/wordpress-increase-media-upload-size/ it's worked for me with wordpress 3.4.1, it just need editing 2 wordpress database entry.

Answer (score 1):

Just try with this one

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' ); in function.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change `upload_max_filesize` in your php.ini:

`upload_max_filesize = 32M`

Answer (score 0):

Try these settings in your .htaccess file:

```
php_value post_max_size 100M
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
```

If that doesn't work, or your code starts throwing an error, then you're probably on a shared host that won't let you increase the size.

Comment: yes thanks you are right. it should shared hosting. so what i have to do now ? any clue ?

Comment: You have a few options:

1. Ping your web host and ask about increasing the upload limit
2. Manually upload the large files via FTP.
3. Switch web hosts

Answer (score 0):

```
1) Use FTP to download a copy of your php.ini file
2) modify that file to have the following lines:
   memory_limit = 100M
   upload_max_filesize = 192M
   post_max_size = 100M
   file_uploads = On
```

3) save, close and rename that file to "php5.ini" and upload it to the wp-admin folder
      of your wordpress install