# wordpress media upload limit

Tags: php, wordpress, php-ini

In my local wordpress site i can just upload files with just 2Megabyte,i have increased the `upload_max_filesize` to 64Mb and restarted wamp but when i run `<?php echo phpinfo()?>` it show `upload_max_filesize = 2M` yet.nothing changed, what should i do to increase upload limit?

i also have visit so many post in stackoverflow and other forums like:[increase-file-upload-size-for-media-in-wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488819/can-any-one-tell-me-how-to-increase-file-upload-size-for-media-in-wordpress)

 and [cannot change php upload size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999439/cannot-change-php-upload-size-limit)
but they didn't help me at all!

Comment: See http://wordpress.org/support/topic/increasing-upload-max-file-size-in-phpini

Comment: i did this change:

post_max_size = 750M 

upload_max_filesize = 750M 
max_execution_time = 5000 

max_input_time = 5000 

memory_limit = 1000M

Comment: Have you tried modifying your `htaccess` as the link suggests?

Comment: i have tried but after creating .htaccess and adding that lines to it an internal error(i think error 500) occured.

Comment: excuse me,there was no error,but i try that and nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed my problem.
I was changing all the time the php.ini in the C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4 folder but the right file was the php.ini of this folder C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.3.14\bin .

and also I understand that for increasing `max_file_uploads` first must increase `post_max_size`, and `max_file_uploads` must be smaller or equal to the `post_max_size`, any other way the codes will be run with default size of `post_max_size`.

tnx all who helped me

Comment: Dude thats exactly what that link I gave you said! Glad you got it sorted in the end.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a Wordpress issue, it's your WAMP Apache settings I would say.  Here's a link to a thread on it on the WAMP forum;

[Increasing WAMP upload limit](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,41520)